# PriorException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#

I have multiple nested methods with try/catch blocks.  If there are any exceptions I want to log the first one and have the flow of control bubble up through the nested methods.  I tried to do this by raising a custom exception called PriorException ...

```
public class PriorException : ApplicationException
{
    public PriorException() : base() { }
    public PriorException(string message) : base(message) { }
}
```

... and writing the catch blocks like so:

```
try
{
    (do stuff here)
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MyLog.ExceptionError(ex);
    if (ex is PriorException) { throw; } else { throw new PriorException(); }
}
```

(MyLog ignores PriorException, and the outermost catch block does NOT rethrow.)

However, what is happening is that when an exception is encountered it is caught, logged, and a PriorException is thrown.  Then control falls out to the calling method where PriorException is caught and rethrown.  But then control moves to the open braces of the else clause of the catch block and the program crashes with "PriorException was unhandled by user code".

I'm still inside one or more nested try/catch blocks which should catch this exception, plus I have AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException wired up for good measure.  So what's going on?

Comment: " But then control moves to the open braces of the else clause of the catch block".  Does this move to open braces occur within the try/catch of the first calling method or the second?  Is this application multithreaded?  Does MyLog.ExceptionError modify ex in any way?

Comment: Okay, I've continued changing this bit by bit, trying to home in on the problem.  The conclusion I've reached is that everything actually works with one exception (no pun intended): At one point in the chain the flow of control is passing through a 3rd party component (a skinned form) and for some reason the debugger can't see the try/catch block through this ... so when an exception (any exception) is raised that *should* fall through this component to reach the try/catch block the debugger is reporting it as unhandled!  Thanks for the help, I guess I need to take this up with the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are debugging. Is the runtime behavior what you expect?

On a side note: I'd highly recommend trying to restructure your code so that you don't have nested try/catch blocks that are being used for program flow. Maintenance could get very tricky as your application progresses.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing

```
try
{
    (do stuff here)
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MyLog.ExceptionError(ex);
    if (ex is PriorException) { throw; } else { throw new PriorException(); }
}
```

you need to add

```
catch (PriorException ex)
{

}
```

right now your only catching general exceptions.

**Edit just realized this is incorrect**

Exception does catch the Prior exception.

What is the need to rethrow the exception once its been handled.

You say that the exception is never touch once the exception has been handled and converted to a type of `ProperException`. Why not just say

```
catch {MyLog.ExceptionError(ex);}
```

and then continue on with your program

Comment: That will also catch "PriorException", since it is a subclass of Exception (via ApplicationException)